# (Python) Singly LinkedList - Leetcode

Tags: python, linked-list

I am working on this Leetcode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/odd-even-linked-list/. 
I already tried to debug the program with the debugging tool and found the bug in my code but I don't really understand the bug and I don't really know how to fix it. The bug came from this line: `odd_head.next = even_head`
Thanks for your help!

The problem is:
Given a singly linked list, group all odd nodes together followed by the even nodes. Please note here we are talking about the node number and not the value in the nodes.

```
For example:
Input: 2->1->3->5->6->4->7->NULL
Output: 2->3->6->7->1->5->4->NULL

Input: 1->2->3->4->5->NULL
Output: 1->3->5->2->4->NULL
```

```
def oddEvenList(self, head):
    odd_head = head
    even_head = head.next

    while(odd_head.next and odd_head.next.next):
        temp = odd_head.next.next
        odd_head.next = temp
        odd_head = temp

    odd_head.next = even_head # BUG ON THIS LINE

    while(even_head.next and even_head.next.next):
        temp = even_head.next.next
        even_head.next = temp
        even_head = temp

    return odd_head
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this list: `2->1->3->5->6->4->7->NULL`

When your code reaches:

```
odd_head.next = even_head
```

Links will be:

```
2->3
3->6
6->7
7->NULL

1->3
5->6
4->7
```

`even_head.next` will be `3`

**`even_head.next.next` will be `6` not `5` (THIS IS WRONG.)**

The reason is that the links are changed in the first while loop! Hence, from here everything starts getting wrong.

---

Out of many possible solutions, one simple solution:

```
def oddEvenList(self, head):
    if not head:
        return head

    odd_head = head
    even_head_copy = even_head = head.next

    while odd_head and even_head and even_head.next:
        odd_head.next = even_head.next
        odd_head = odd_head.next

        even_head.next = odd_head.next
        even_head = even_head.next

    odd_head.next = even_head_copy
    return head
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it make senses why it gets stuck in the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

A proper solution would be:

```
class Solution:
    def oddEvenList(self, head):
        try:
            odd = head
            even_head=head.next
            even = head.next
            cur=even.next
        except:
            return head
        try:
            while cur!=None:
                odd.next=cur
                odd=odd.next
                even.next=cur.next
                even=even.next
                cur=cur.next.next
                print(even.val)
        except:
            pass
        odd.next=even_head
        return head
```

The first try block is to initialize the variable and handle the corner case where the list have less than 2 elements. The second try block looping through the list.